# how to delete tiller from kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Tiller is not working properly in my kubernetes cluster.  I want to delete everything Tiller.  Tiller (2.5.1) has 1 Deployment, 1 ReplicaSet and 1 Pod.

**I tried:  kubectl delete deployment tiller-deploy -n kube-system**

- results in "deployment "tiller-deploy" deleted"
- however, tiller-deploy is immediately recreated
- kubectl get deployments -n kube-system shows tiller-deploy running again

**I also tried:  kubectl delete rs tiller-deploy-393110584 -n kube-system**

- results in "replicaset "tiller-deploy-2745651589" deleted"
- however, tiller-deploy-2745651589 is immediately recreated
- kubectl get rs -n kube-system shows tiller-deploy-2745651589 running again

**What is the correct way to permanently delete Tiller?**

Comment: Could you please set Nickolay's answer as accepted?

Answer (score 91):

To uninstall tiller from a kubernetes cluster:

```
helm reset
```

To delete failed tiller from a kubernetes cluster:

```
helm reset --force
```

Comment: can we delete the tiller without deleting the helm charts deployed? i want to get rid of tiller once i deploy the chart , because keep running tiller is not secure

Comment: @IjazAhmadKhan That's a weird use case, but you can just scale down to 0 the tiller deployment

Comment: I have fixed this by running tiller with low priv role

Comment: (Tip: use --force to remove Tiller. Releases will not be deleted.)

Answer (score 37):

If you want to remove **tiller** from your cluster the cleanest way it's by removing all the components deployed during the installation.

If you already know the namespace where tiller its deployed:

```sh
$ kubectl delete all -l app=helm -n kube-system
pod "tiller-deploy-8557598fbc-5b2g7" deleted
service "tiller-deploy" deleted
deployment.apps "tiller-deploy" deleted
replicaset.apps "tiller-deploy-75f6c87b87" deleted
replicaset.apps "tiller-deploy-8557598fbc" deleted
```

> Be careful with the command, will delete all in the namespace indicated and
>   with the corresponding label.

where `app` its the label assigned and will identify all component(replication controller, deployments, service, etc).

You can describe the pod to verify the labels:

```sh
$ kubectl describes pod tiller-deploy-8557598fbc-5b2g7 -n kube-system
Name: tiller-deploy-8557598fbc-5b2g7
Namespace: kube-system
Priority: 0
PriorityClassName: <none>
Node: srvlpi03 / 192.168.1.133
Start Time: Tue, 20 Aug 2019 15:51:03 -0400
Labels: app = helm
        name = tiller
        pod-template-hash = 8557598fbc
```

Answer (score 10):

You have to uninstall 3 things to completely get rid of tiller:

1. Deployment
2. Service
3. Secret

```
    kubectl delete deployment -n some-namespace tiller-deploy 
    kubectl delete svc -n some-namespace tiller-deploy 
    kubectl delete secret -n some-namespace tiller-secret
```

Be sure to backup the secret as it store all the certificates if TLS is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try below command

```
kubectl delete deployment tiller-deploy --namespace kube-system
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that it was running as replicaset:

```
kubectl delete replicasets -n kube-system tiller-deploy-6fdb84698b
```

worked for me

`helm reset --force` didn't remove the tiller.

Answer (score 0):

Kubectl get hpa --all-namespaces( OR -n kube-system)

In normal tiller deployment, they use replica set. For your set up there might be a HorizontalPodAutoscaler object which is targeting the replica sets for tiller.

You can delete the HPA first and then delete the associated replicasets, pods, configmaps OR you can reset helm using "helm reset" command.

Answer (score 0):

don't forget

kubectl -n kube-system delete service tiller-deploy