# Reset / Rollback Kubernetes to just create state?

Tags: kubernetes, reset

i am trying to setup a complete GitLab Routine to setup my Kubernetes Cluster with all installations and configurations automatically incl. decommissioning at the end.

However the Creation and Decommissioning Progress is one of the most time consuming because i am basically waiting for the provisioning till i can execute further commands.

as i have some times troubles in the bases of the Kubernetes Setup, i currently decomission my cluster and create a new one. But this is pretty un-economical and time consuming.

Question:
Is there a command or a series of commands to completely reset a Kubernetes to his state after creation ?

Answer (score 1):

The closest is probably to do all your work in a new namespace and then delete that namespace when you are done. That automatically deletes all objects inside it.

Comment: That wont work as i tried already the deletion of all content but i have trouble explicitely with the Tiller now which already exists in the cluster and is in the kubernetes-base namespace

Comment: You can set the namespace to use for Tiller. Also probably don't use Tiller, it's going away very soon.

Comment: May I request you to please confirm whether you have tried deleting the service, deployments and secrets manually via kubectl? If that has not worked, take a look at the link below. It explain various ways to remove tiller from the cluster.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47583821/how-to-delete-tiller-from-kubernetes-cluster

Comment: You mean just trying deleting really everything ? also the kubernetes base ? I cna give this a try

Comment: It caused some weird behaviour on the Kubernetes cluster... for now i stick with decom and reordering the cluster if necessary... however as it is now running quite fluent i wont see the need in near future. I will however post an update as soon as i have a solution.